# Netbeans update generated project files from command line

Tags: java, jenkins, netbeans, continuous-integration

I need to setup a periodic pull & build of a native Netbeans project on a Linux box and I don't want to open the project in the Netbeans GUI to make the generated files up-to-date.

There can be at least one file in a native Netbeans project that should be different on different machines: `nbproject/private/private.properties`. Here's an example of a web application to build for Glassfish:

```
deploy.ant.properties.file=/home/admin/.netbeans/8.2/config/GlassFishEE6/Properties/gfv3-155092097.properties
j2ee.platform.is.jsr109=true
j2ee.server.domain=/opt/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
j2ee.server.home=/opt/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish
j2ee.server.instance=[/opt/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish:/opt/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1]deployer:gfv3ee6wc:localhost:4848
j2ee.server.middleware=/opt/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4
user.properties.file=/home/admin/.netbeans/8.2/build.properties
```

It is not under version control, but without it `Ant` cannot build projects that use the Glassfish server registered in Netbeans:

```
[admin@funktest v24testear]$ ant -quiet clean dist
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 16 seconds

[admin@funktest v24testear]$ rm -f nbproject/private/private.properties

[admin@funktest v24testear]$ ant -quiet clean dist
BUILD FAILED
/home/admin/Downloads/v24test/v24testear/nbproject/build-impl.xml:156: The libs.CopyLibs.classpath property is not set up.
```

There's also `build-impl.xml` that is derived from `project.xml` and I would like to re-generate it too.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround to this is including and referencing the required lib in your project. For example:

1. locate the JAR-file `org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar`, which will typically reside in a location like `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\ant\extra` on a computer with NetBeans.
2. Copy that JAR into your project, f.x. `project/ant/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar`.
3. Open `nbproject/project.properties` and at the end of it add the line:

   ```
   libs.CopyLibs.classpath=ant/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
   ```

With the lib in your project and project.properties pointing to its location Ant should be able to build without an actual NetBeans installation.